# Generating sets for a module and scalar extension

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $K/k$ a (transcendental) field extension. Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $k$-algebra, and $M$ an $A$-module. Suppose that the $K \otimes_k A$-module $K \otimes_k M$ is cyclic, i.e. is generated by a single element. Is it necessarily true that $M$ is a cyclic $A$-module?

More generally, it seems clear to me that a generating set for $M$ will extend to a generating set for $K \otimes_k M$. But is it necessarily true that if $K\otimes_k M$ can be generated by $n$ elements, then $M$ has a generating set of $n$ elements? I'm most interested in the case where $A = kG$ for $G$ a finite group, so if the above fails, is it at least true for group algebras?

Comment: If $A$ is commutative (and $K/k$ is an arbitrary field extension), it seems true for the following reason (if I'm correct): $M$ is not generated by $\le n-1$ elements iff there exists a nonzero module $N$ such that $M$ surjects onto $N^n$. This condition passes to extension of scalars. I don't know if such a criterion holds in the noncommutative case.

Comment: (Above, I assume $M$ finitely generated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is yes, by the following argument. Let $J(A)$ be the Jacobson radical of $A$. As $k$ is algebraically closed, by the Wedderburn theorem $A/J(A)$ is a direct product of matrix algebras over $k$. In this situation we have $J(K\otimes_k A)=K\otimes_k J(A)$. Since you're interested in the number of generators, you might as well replace $A$ by $A/J(A)$ and $M$ by $M/J(A)M$. Then $M$ is a direct sum of simple modules. Extending the field on a simple module still gives a simple module. Since $k$ is infinite, the number of generators of a direct sum of simple modules is determined by the multiplicities and dimensions of the simples. In particular, it is independent of the field extension.